# Combined likelihood and max likelihood estimator of two normal distributions

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

[image]

Hi guys I have been going through a bank of revision questions in prep for an exam and have come across this question that I cannot seem to solve. My work so far:

For part a, am I correct in assuming that since both distributions are independent that you take the log likelihood functions of both distributions and then add them together? With the log likelihood being $-\frac{n}{2} \ln(2π)-\frac{n}{2}\ln(σ^2)-\frac{1}{2σ^2}\sum_{j=1}^n(x_j -μ)$ for $x$.

For part b I am more unsure about as to what to do, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: For the first part, what is combined likelihood ratio? My best guess is the multiplication of all likelihoods since they are independent and then taking their log.

For part two use $L=\log(p(\mathbf{y},\hat{\sigma}_2)/p(\mathbf{x},\hat{\sigma}_1))$ where $\hat{\sigma}_1$ and $\hat{\sigma}_2$ are as given in the question.

Comment: Both population means are 0. Otherwise, this seems to be the same situation discussed in Zhang, Xi, and Chen: "The exact likelihood ratio test for equality of two normal populations": _The American Statistician_ v66 n3, Aug 2012, pp180-184, Because that paper is over five years old, it should be freely available on JSTOR.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you add those, but since it was assumed to be known that $\mu=0,$ you can just drop $\mu.$ Also, you didn't square the term in the sum. Where you had $\sigma$ you need $\sigma_1,$ and then when you do this with $m$ rather than $n$ you need $\sigma_2.$ For the likelihood under the null hypothesis you won't need to estimate two different parameters.